# Is it necessary hold references to children in parent document -Mongooose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In below example, I want to retrieve post document filled with corresponding comments.

Do I need to hold references to comments in post as an array? Holding array with reference to comments would mean that the post document would be updated quite regularly whenever a new document is updated.

```
 var Post = new schema({
       content:String,
       author:{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
       createdOn:Date
    });

var Comment = new Schema({
   post : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' },
   commentText : String,
   author: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
   createdOn:Date
});
mongoose.model('Post',Post);
mongoose.model('Comment',Comment);
```

If I hold references of Comment._Id in Post as an array, then in mongoose I can populate as below.

```
Post.findById(postid).populate('Comments').exec( callback);
```

But I do not want to update post document whenever a new a comment is created as you need to push the comment id into post document. Comment has reference to Post which it belongs, so technically speaking, it is possible to retrieve comments belonging to a particular post, but if you want to retrieve or send single json document  is it possible without having array containing references to comments in post document?

Comment: Yes, but you will need two queries. A query for your post and a query for all your comments. Then you will have to return both results :)

Comment: Thanks Thomas, Yeah thats the way forward I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always with data modelling there are just multiple ways to do things with advantages/disadvantages. Often more than one way is good enough for your app.

The question you are asking is a typical 1:n relationship, so you may:

1. store backrefs from the children to the parent
2. store an array of refs on the parent to the children
3. store two-way referencing by doing 1. and 2.
4. store the comments directly inside the post object as an array of sub-documents (comment-objects) inside the post-document.

Each of these is correct and works. Which one is the best really depends on your usage - your app. Examples:

- If you have lots of concurrent creates of comments for one post, then 1. is probably a good choice, because you don't need to concurrently update the post object. But you will always need two queries to display a Post with its comments.
- If you are never displaying a comment without its post, and if one comment always belongs to exactly one post, 4. may be a good choice - probably the typical choice with mongodb (a no-sql choice). -> Only one query to display a post with comments.
- If you have single posts with lots of comments and it is important for your performance to be able to load only a subset of comments, 4. is a bad choice.
- 3. is probably best if you need all flexibilty, whenever you cannot predict the usage and performance is not an issue.

further info here: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/

Comment: Thanks Reto. This was quite useful. I am feeling option 1 may be better choice for me. On option 2 and 3, i feel it still requires two queries. Even if mongoose populate is used,  under the hood, when debug is enabled, i find it fires two queries. I wish mongoose had populate option to when option is used. Option 4 , I am inclined not to use as the comments can increase the document size and if multiple users are updating documents, then it would have impact on performance.

Comment: you are right in that 2 and 3 require 2 queries under the hood. Population happens in the node.js code. 
So I agree that 1 or 4 are better for your case: 1 optimizes write performance, 4 optimizes read performance. So if you have lots of "write once", "read many times" data then use 4. If you have lots of writes that are rarely read (like a logging type app) then certainly use 1.

Comment: I will also add that one needs to consider the size of the document. 4. might not be an option if you expect long discussions.